# Paypal API PHP SetExpressCheckout failed: couldn't connect to host(7)

Tags: api, curl, paypal

I have this code and it returns

```
**SetExpressCheckout failed: couldn't connect to host(7)**
```

It was working earlier and not it decided to stop working. I really don't know if it's an old code.

`$paypal= new MyPayPal();`

`$httpParsedResponseAr = $paypal->PPHttpPost('SetExpressCheckout', $padata, $PayPalApiUsername, $PayPalApiPassword, $PayPalApiSignature, $PayPalMode);`

in MyPaypal I have the following:

```
class MyPayPal { function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_, $PayPalApiUsername,  $PayPalApiPassword, $PayPalApiSignature, $PayPalMode) {
            // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
            $API_UserName = urlencode($PayPalApiUsername);
            $API_Password = urlencode($PayPalApiPassword);
            $API_Signature = urlencode($PayPalApiSignature);

        $paypalmode = ($PayPalMode=='sandbox') ? '.sandbox' : '';

        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t".$paypalmode.".paypal.com/nvp";
        $version = urlencode('109.0');

        // Set the curl parameters.
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

        // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
        $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

        // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

        // Get response from the server.
        $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

        if(!$httpResponse) {
            exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
        }

        // Extract the response details.
        $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

        $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
        foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
            $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
            if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
                $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
            }
        }

        if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
            exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
        }

    return $httpParsedResponseAr;
}
}
```